# Redhat Couchbase Server image/container doesn't respond to http://localhost:8091

Tags: openshift, couchbase, redhat

I am using couchbase server 6.0.2 image from RedHat

https://access.redhat.com/containers/?tab=overview&get-method=registry-tokens#/registry.connect.redhat.com/couchbase/server

in openshift.

The Pod is running but does not react to http://localhost:8091. The Logs show the error shown below.

I have 3 questions:

1. Why is whoami failing in the entrypoint?
2. Why isn't the server responding on port 8091?
3. Does the couchbase server image require root permissions?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems the couchbase/server image is expecting to be run as root, then creates its own user `couchbase` and group `couchbase`.
At the end it's running an entrypoint script and in there checking if the user running the whole thing, is actually the user `couchbase` by executing the `whois` command.

This is not the case if you just run it in openshift, as the container will be run as some "random" unprivileged user.

This leads to a set of consecutive failures:

[Here](https://github.com/couchbase/docker/blob/562480118b2f860fdacfc8b06d55b37fd7f9e41e/enterprise/couchbase-server/6.0.2/scripts/entrypoint.sh#L44) You will find the evaluation that is done in the `entrypoint.sh`.
Now the `whois` command is failing since there is not actual user just said random UID. that failing, leaves the first part of the evaluation blank, which will result in a failure.

This is a bug in the couchbase/server image and as such you should, if time allows contribute to fixing by opening an issue against that repo.

Comment: What made you say that couchbase/server image is expecting to be run as root? in the entrypoint.sh I can only see that whoami is checking for 'couchbase'.

Comment: Here https://github.com/couchbase/docker/tree/562480118b2f860fdacfc8b06d55b37fd7f9e41e/enterprise/couchbase-server/6.0.2 it is mentioned that you can run the server as non-root (paragraph Running the container as non-root user)

Comment: because the default is to run it as root and you have not stated anywhere, that you took steps to change that behavior. Basically it's an assumption of mine.